# Load Php Page Inside Jquery Chrome Tabs

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I am Trying to Implement a Tab Like interface For my Php Project. For this I have added below Jquery `chrome tabs` https://github.com/adamschwartz/chrome-tabs/, It is working fine but I am not finding any way to load different php page inside each individual tab. I have added tab adding event inside below function passing url as parameter.

```
function loadTab(url)
{
    el.addEventListener('activeTabChange', ({ detail }) => console.log('Active tab changed', detail.tabEl))
    el.addEventListener('tabAdd', ({ detail }) => console.log('Tab added', detail.tabEl))
    el.addEventListener('tabRemove', ({ detail }) => console.log('Tab removed', detail.tabEl))

    chromeTabs.addTab({
      title: url,
      favicon: false,
              data: {
                timeAdded: +new Date(),
              }
    })
}

Calling the function from click event is adding tab and taking the url as tab title.How can I load php page inside the tab like below or any other way. Pls suggest
$(elem).load("ajax/page_url.php");
```

Comment: I would place the AJAX loading in the activeTabChange event handler.

Comment: I tried like this  `el.addEventListener('activeTabChange', ({ detail }) => $('.mock-browser-content').load("ac-manage-concern.php"))` , Problem is all tabs are getting last url, I need to keep different url in each tab

Comment: I did not look into the docs, but I bet you can access like `el.addEventListener('activeTabChange', ({ detail }) => $('.mock-browser-content').load(detail.title))`;

Comment: problem is every tab is getting this `mock-browser-content` div class, so always last url is updating to every tab

Comment: Either you have **one** content tab and replace the content. Or each tab has it's own content. On activation, you could hide all ".content" and just _unhide_ the current one.

Comment: but every tab is showing the same last url, that is the problem

Comment: Yes, because your query selector sets all tabs. You must set it for the active tab!

Comment: it is updating only tab id  like this `.chrome-tabs[data-chrome-tabs-instance-id="0"] .chrome-tab:nth-child(3) {
            transform: translate3d(478px, 0, 0)
          }` But Not updating any content div id or class for each tab